# How to use Excel to generate a folders containing a wordfile of the same name?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, filenames

I am a tech writer, and I am looking for a way to streamline my software-release workflow. With every release, we get an Excel file of changes that contains a request number and a description. Our department creates a word document for each change, and uses the request number and description for the title of each document. Since these files contain images and other files, I always create a folder of the same name from this excel sheet to hold all of the changes for each release. I use this bit of code to generate the files:

```
Sub MakeFolders()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
Set Rng = Selection
maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
For c = 1 To maxCols
r = 1
Do While r <= maxRows
If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
On Error Resume Next
End If
r = r + 1
Loop
Next c
End Sub
```

I am wondering: is there a way to ALSO generate a word file in each of these folders with the same name?

Comment: note that `Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer` doesn't define all these variables as integer. Excel only looks to the next comma, so the first 3 are `Variant` and only the last is integer.  
Once you have a folder, could you copy a blank (prepared) document to that location?

Comment: Yes; I thought of doing that too. It would take about 30 seconds to move the files over. However, I can't find anything that does for Word documents what the script above for folders; i.e., create a bunch of word documents based on cells in excel.

Answer (score 1):

The Office default namespace should already have the ability to create Word documents, Excel Workbooks, PowerPoints, etc.  The capability is a little hidden because you need to use the `CreateObject` function which accepts a string identifier, which ultimately is the type name of the object you want to create.  In this case you want `"Word.Application"`.  Word.Application is not yet a Word document, its exactly what it sounds like (an object reference to the Microsoft Word Application itself).  This should get you started.

```
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
With wordDoc
    .SaveAs ("C:/SomeDirectory/SomeDoc.docx")
    ' VERY IMPORTANT TO CLOSE THE DOCUMENT
    .Close
End With

' Close the Microsoft Word Application
wordApp.Quit 

' Always cleanup your variables when you are done
Set wordDoc = Nothing
Set wordApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a lot of help. Is there a way to make the file name above ("SomeDoc.docx") come from a range of cells or even a single highlighted cell? I created directories from a column in excel, and I am hoping to recreate this with word documents.

Comment: There is a `Text` property on Ranges.  Single cells are still considered ranges they just have a single cell as the start and end of its range definition (technically).  Here's the documentation on the `Text` property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-text-property-excel

Its not very helpful documentation, but at least its something.  Ultimately, you would do something like:

`Set fileName = myrange.Text
...
worDoc.SaveAs(fileName)`